# drupal_add_js and drupal_flush_all_caches

Tags: 7, forms, javascript, performance

I was trying to call `drupal_add_js` in the callback of a button. It seems, even with after_build, that this can be done successfully only you are working without cached data.

So, before i start the page, i run `drupal_flush_all_caches`, and the javascript is successfully added to the page.

The problem is I want to get some user input data from a form, pass to the javascript and exibit the result. The way i'm trying to do, it is getting a string that contains the processed values and concatenating with another string that contains the other part of the javascript (probably this is not a good practice), and calling this string with `drupal_add_js`. But, when if i call `drupal_flush_all_caches`, the form will be reset and i will not be able to get the data.

So, my questions are: How can i pass values from a form to a javascript?

Do i need to flush all caches every time to use `drupal_add_js`?

Is there different solutions to deal with this during development and production?

---

Thanks for the help guys. I found some answers:   How can i pass values from a form to a javascript? I had to name my variable as `Drupal.settings.myModule.myVar` in the javascript code. This way i can pass variables from php code to javascript. If you want to modify the javascript code you really need to flush caches. Until now, i have not found nothing about differences between production and development best pratices.

Comment: Do you pass only data from the user function to the javascript which is added to the page, or also javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any problem with writing a menu callback that does this, and processing in PHP?

If you must use JavaScript for the processing, why not intercept the user's value in JavaScript and never "really" submit the form?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add the javascript using Drupal.behaviors. This will ensure that the javascript code gets reloaded even if the page is cached.